# python3 sqlalchemy проблема при продолжительном подключении к базе данных

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

Я использую `sqlalchemy scoped_session` для работы с базой данных `Postgresql`. Так происходит создание session():

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from contextlib import contextmanager
Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('postgresql://пользователь:пароль@localhost:5432/users',
                       pool_size=100,
                       max_overflow=100,
                       echo=True)
@contextmanager
def session():
    connection = engine.connect()
    db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=True, autoflush=True, bind=engine))
    try:
        yield db_session
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        db_session.remove()
        connection.close()
```

А вот так я это использую:

```
with session() as ssion:
    *какой-то код*
```

Блок with вызывается Flask'ом и примерно через 10 минут в консоли появляется ошибка (во время вызова метода):

```
psycopg2.DatabaseError: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected
```

Я пробовал изменять значения pool_size, max_overflow на больше - не помогло, пробовал ставить autoflush=False, что также не помогло

**UPD1** Логи Postgresql:

```
2018-05-10 19:51:23 MSK [9087-193] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: ROLLBACK
2018-05-10 19:52:26 MSK [9088-181] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: BEGIN
2018-05-10 19:52:26 MSK [9088-182] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: select * from users_activity where score=(select max(score) from users_activity);
2018-05-10 19:52:26 MSK [9088-183] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: ROLLBACK
2018-05-10 19:52:26 MSK [9088-184] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: BEGIN
2018-05-10 19:52:26 MSK [9088-185] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: select * from users_activity where sub_date=(select max(sub_date) from users_activity);
2018-05-10 19:52:26 MSK [9088-186] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: ROLLBACK
2018-05-10 19:53:27 MSK [9087-194] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: BEGIN
2018-05-10 19:53:27 MSK [9087-195] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: select * from users_activity where score=(select max(score) from users_activity);
2018-05-10 19:53:27 MSK [9087-196] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: ROLLBACK
2018-05-10 19:53:27 MSK [9087-197] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: BEGIN
2018-05-10 19:53:27 MSK [9087-198] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: select * from users_activity where sub_date=(select max(sub_date) from users_activity);
2018-05-10 19:53:27 MSK [9087-199] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: ROLLBACK
2018-05-10 19:53:28 MSK [10577-16] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: BEGIN
2018-05-10 19:53:28 MSK [10577-17] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: select * from users where id=466818033;
2018-05-10 19:53:28 MSK [10577-18] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: select * from users where id=466818033
2018-05-10 19:53:30 MSK [10577-19] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: COMMIT
2018-05-10 19:54:13 MSK [10577-20] pibotuser@users LOG:  SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac
2018-05-10 19:54:13 MSK [10577-21] pibotuser@users LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2018-05-10 19:54:28 MSK [9088-187] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: BEGIN
2018-05-10 19:54:28 MSK [9088-188] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: select * from users_activity where score=(select max(score) from users_activity);
2018-05-10 19:54:28 MSK [9088-189] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: ROLLBACK
2018-05-10 19:54:28 MSK [9088-190] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: BEGIN
2018-05-10 19:54:28 MSK [9088-191] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: select * from users_activity where sub_date=(select max(sub_date) from users_activity);
2018-05-10 19:54:28 MSK [9088-192] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: ROLLBACK
2018-05-10 19:55:29 MSK [9087-200] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: BEGIN
2018-05-10 19:55:29 MSK [9087-201] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: select * from users_activity where score=(select max(score) from users_activity);
2018-05-10 19:55:29 MSK [9087-202] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: ROLLBACK
2018-05-10 19:55:30 MSK [9087-203] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: BEGIN
2018-05-10 19:55:30 MSK [9087-204] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: select * from users_activity where sub_date=(select max(sub_date) from users_activity);
2018-05-10 19:55:30 MSK [9087-205] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: ROLLBACK
2018-05-10 19:56:31 MSK [9088-193] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: BEGIN
2018-05-10 19:56:31 MSK [9088-194] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: select * from users_activity where score=(select max(score) from users_activity);
2018-05-10 19:56:31 MSK [9088-195] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: ROLLBACK
2018-05-10 19:56:31 MSK [9088-196] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: BEGIN
2018-05-10 19:56:31 MSK [9088-197] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: select * from users_activity where sub_date=(select max(sub_date) from users_activity);
2018-05-10 19:56:31 MSK [9088-198] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: ROLLBACK
2018-05-10 19:57:32 MSK [9087-206] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: BEGIN
2018-05-10 19:57:32 MSK [9087-207] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: select * from users_activity where score=(select max(score) from users_activity);
2018-05-10 19:57:32 MSK [9087-208] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: ROLLBACK
2018-05-10 19:57:32 MSK [9087-209] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: BEGIN
2018-05-10 19:57:32 MSK [9087-210] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: select * from users_activity where sub_date=(select max(sub_date) from users_activity);
2018-05-10 19:57:32 MSK [9087-211] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: ROLLBACK
2018-05-10 19:58:33 MSK [9088-199] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: BEGIN
2018-05-10 19:58:33 MSK [9088-200] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: select * from users_activity where score=(select max(score) from users_activity);
2018-05-10 19:58:33 MSK [9088-201] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: ROLLBACK
2018-05-10 19:58:34 MSK [9088-202] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: BEGIN
2018-05-10 19:58:34 MSK [9088-203] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: select * from users_activity where sub_date=(select max(sub_date) from users_activity);
2018-05-10 19:58:34 MSK [9088-204] pibotuser@users LOG:  statement: ROLLBACK
```

**UPD2**
Я запустил следующий код:

```
while True:
    with session() as ssion:
        ssion.execute('select * from users')
        ssion.execute('update users set mode=0')
```

Он работал на это базе данных минут 5 и ошибка не произошла. Похоже, проблема именно в рабочем коде, но я не знаю, как ее обнаружить

Comment: это выглядит как ошибка на стороне postgresql. Проверьте какие запросы выполняются, когда ошибка возникает. Посмотрите логи. Есть ли свободная память, место на диске?

Comment: @jfs Память и место есть. Как мне посмотреть логи бд?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-logging.html

Comment: @jfs я добавил логи

Comment: и в какой момент ошибка у вас произошла?

Comment: Не уверен, но в 19:54:13 @jfs

Comment: почему вы думаете, что это та же ошибка? Запустите ваш код, чтобы воспроизвести ошибку и быть уверенным когда точно ошибка произошла.

Comment: @jfs нет, ошибка та же

Comment: вы запустили код и получили `psycopg2.DatabaseError` в коде и SSL error в логе в то же время?

Comment: @jfs проблема в том, что ошибка проявляется абсолютно случайно. Код может работать от пары минут до нескольких часов (сегодня проработал около 10). Я думаю, что это связанно с активностью пользователей (этот ужас на продакшене, я не знаю, даже какой костыль поставить). Могла быть ошибка `could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer`

Comment: @jfs я сделал еще одно обновление

Comment: @jfs получилось вызвать ошибку. Это две строки:
`SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac`
`could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer`

Comment: попробуйте `create_engine(...., pool_pre_ping=True)` 
 http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#pool-disconnects-pessimistic